# Combining two identical javascripts into one

Tags: javascript, function, panel

I've searched but frankly, do not know enough about JS to make sense of all of the other "combine these 2 functions" posts already out there.

I am using a script to slide out a Contact Panel. I duplicated this script to then slide out the About Panel.

I want to consolidate both into one script to tidy things up. Possible?

Contact Panel:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">            
    function showContactPanel() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("contact-panel");
    if (elem.classList) {
      elem.classList.toggle("show");
    } else {
      var classes = elem.className;
      if (classes.indexOf("show") >= 0) {
        elem.className = classes.replace("show", "");
      } else {
        elem.className = classes + " show"; 
      }
      console.log(elem.className);
    }
    }
</script>
```

Duplicated for the About Panel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
    function showAboutPanel() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("about-panel");
    if (elem.classList) {
      elem.classList.toggle("show");
    } else {
      var classes = elem.className;
      if (classes.indexOf("show") >= 0) {
        elem.className = classes.replace("show", "");
      } else {
        elem.className = classes + " show"; 
      }
      console.log(elem.className);
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: link it as an external script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the panel ID as a parameter:

```
function showPanel(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if (elem.classList) {
        elem.classList.toggle("show");
    } else {
        var classes = elem.className;
        if (classes.indexOf("show") >= 0) {
            elem.className = classes.replace("show", "");
        } else {
            elem.className = classes + " show"; 
        }
        console.log(elem.className);
    }
}
```

and then call it that way:

```
showPanel("about-panel");
```

or

```
showPanel("contact-panel");
```

Answer (score 2):

So change your function signature to take a parameter for the element in question:

```
function showPanel(panelId) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(panelId);
    ...
```

and call it:

```
showPanel("contact-panel");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the id of the panel as an argument to the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
    function showPanel(panelId) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(panelId);
    if (elem.classList) {
      elem.classList.toggle("show");
    } else {
      var classes = elem.className;
      if (classes.indexOf("show") >= 0) {
        elem.className = classes.replace("show", "");
      } else {
        elem.className = classes + " show"; 
      }
      console.log(elem.className);
    }
    }
</script>
```

See [JavaScript Function Parameters](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp) for more information on function parameters.